# Do not know why the master node is not running

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an iRobot create, and after installing my packages and running a script, I get the error: *Unable to register with master node [http://tahoma:11311]: master way not be running yet.*

This seems to be a common problem, but I haven't been able to make the troubleshooting solutions work. I ran *roscore* - no errors pop up, and I expected this would start up the master node. But running the script still returns the original error.

What explanations could there be for the master node to not be running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65182/do-not-know-why-the-master-node-is-not-running/) by [brein](https://answers.ros.org/users/5156/brein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may be a problem with your `$ROS_MASTER_URI` variable.  That is, roscore is running under a different master URI than the other process.  Try running `echo $ROS_MASTER_URI` in the terminal running roscore and the terminal running your other process. If they are different you can use `export ROS_MASTER_URI=<whatever your roscore master uri is>` in the terminal window running the other process to set the variable to the proper URI before running the process. You can also add the export line to your .bashrc file to set the correct ROS_MASTER_URI in every new terminal.

You can read [ROS Network Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) for more information on setting up your machine.

---

Originally posted by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) with karma: 259 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-14**:
It's more likely that you can't reach the master than it's not running.  Go through the network setup guide to make sure you have everything setup correctly.

**Comment by [brein](https://answers.ros.org/users/5156/brein/) on 2013-06-15**:
you were both right, that was exactly it. thanks a lot you guys, I understand much better how ROS runs now

**Comment by [A.Sami](https://answers.ros.org/users/54131/a.sami/) on 2020-04-29**:
can you tell me about the network setup thing ?